# Airlines with an emigrating allowance?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

Was debating putting this on expats.SE, but it's more about the travel part, so here goes.

A friend is emigrating with their family and they have heard some airlines have an 'emigration allowance' - ie more bags / weight.

However, neither they nor I can find a definitive list of airlines supporting this.

Any such list out there?

If it helps, they're flying from the UK to New Zealand.

Comment: Didn't even know there is such a thing. That would have been useful when I learned that even in three months living abroad I can amass quite a bunch of stuff.

Comment: I think your first inkling was correct. This more proper should be posted on [expatriates.se]. Regardless of whether it is "more about the travel" or not, they would be more familiar with rules and regulations regarding traveling during emigration.

Comment: The only airline that I have heard of that offers emigrant baggage allowances is Jet Airways and that offer applies only to India citizens emigrating the first time.  Don't know of any carriers offering the same on UK - NZ routes.

Comment: Many employers in the middle east offer to pay for extra luggage for employees coming for the first time, or leaving for good. Perhaps this is what you heard about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some routes where this is applied; for example from the ME to Asia there are special exceptions on luggage weight on some airlines (Kuwait Airways, for example).

A few airlines I have flown on before have such allowances; but I have only heard of them for students and *repatriation*; but not for immigration and then not between those two countries specifically.

A while ago, there was some hope:

> Singapore Airlines offer a double baggage allowance (from the usual
>   20Kg to 40Kg) providing you are holding an unused migrant visa that
>   states to remain in Australia indefinitely.  If you hold a valid visa,
>   you will be entitled to the double baggage allowance on production of
>   the visa at check-in.

However I cannot find this reference anywhere on the current website.

Comment: Double checked baggage allowance is relatively common on some routes. For example, from Europe to Japan there are currently at least six airlines which allow two checked baggage (generally of up to 23kg each) instead of one, for all passengers (namely, JAL, ANA, Lufthansa, Swiss, Austrian, and Air China). This does not apply to OP's situation, however. (Not to mention that even a double allowance may not be sufficient for emigrating.)

Comment: Its not the number, its the weight that's a concern. As a general rule (unless you are traveling on a budget airline), all travel classes allow two checked bags - the only limit being the weight of the individual pieces.

Comment: In my experience, the general rule is only one checked bag for economy class. Also, if you consider two bags to be the general rule, I am not sure what is the "double baggage allowance" you refer to in your answer. 40kg per bag?

Comment: That's exactly what it is, its double the weight. As I said, the rule will differ based on the airline you are flying. For example, Emirates allows two bags of 30 KG total weight (economy); in other classes the weight goes up but the number of pieces remain the same. On some routes, the individual weights differ. BA for example, offers 2 bags allowance on most routes for Economy; but they do have 1 bag fares (as a discount option).

Comment: Right, "total weight". What I was referring to was two bags of 23kg *each*, for a total of 46kg. For the routes I usually fly (from Europe to North America or Japan), one bag of up to 23kg (sometimes 20) is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of such an allowance on all flights from a given airline. However, while I don't remember the specifics, I did hear about some specific routes where extra luggage was allowed in some cases (and Tom mentioned another one in a comment). Consequently, rather than a list of airlines, it might be useful to scour the net for forum posts, using the departure and destination and “emigration” or “luggage” as keywords.